# SQL query not working properly in C# while a lot of data is applied one by one

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a problem while reading from SQL Server in C#. It is happening in SSIS, I have inserted a C# script in data flow.

I am using the code below:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string vendorName = Row.VendorName.ToString().Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + Row.VendorName.ToString().Substring(1);
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select TOP 1 * from Logs where MessageId = '" + Row.id.ToString() + "'" +
                                "AND name = (Select Id from Names where vendor_name = '" + vendorName +
                                "order by CreatedDate desc", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string status = "";
        using (SqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (oReader.Read())
            {
                status = oReader["Status"].ToString();
            }
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
        {
            SaveDataToDB(Row.id, Row.VendorName, "Unknown");
        }
    }
}
```

In the Logs table, there are about 10000 rows, and the related datasource, where Row data belongs to, has around 9000 records. The problem is that, even though the query is working well, in the script it sometimes brings status value as null, because it cannot find the record in the SQL. I am getting the query and copy/pasting it to SQL, executing the query brings result there, but not in C# somehow. For example, I am running the C# two times in sequence, at the first time it says Status is null for the id: 354456, but when I run it at the second time it finds 354456 correctly but saying that status of 354499 is null.

Any idea for me to solve this issue? I really appreciate for any help.

Comment: Is your Logs getting updated by another process?

Comment: Nope, it is not

Comment: I suppose that are just typos but your query syntax is wrong (missing spaces and closing quotes) By the way, any reason about not using parameters?

Comment: are the MessageId and the RowId ever related..? if so change the query to utilize a Join can you run the query inside of Sql Server Enterprise..?

Comment: MessageId = RowId for this case.

The query is working well for more than 8000 records, copy/paste it to sql and execute also works for the cases status=null (in the sql I can see their status and they are not null, they should not be null in the script too)

Comment: well perhaps you need a better where clause `AND STATUS IS NOT NULL` get with a DBA to help you tweak your Sql

Answer (score 0):

your code is really inefficient, you should cache vendorname in a string and do all the substring operations on that.

for example:

```
 string vendorName = Convert.ToString(Row.VendorName);
 vendorName = vendorName.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + vendorName.Substring(1);
```

instead of selecting all the columns, select the specific column for a speed up `select Status from`.

try to debug your code first, see which id you are getting and what is the result of your query.

its really hard to debug your code without any debug information.

change your code to this `(Select Id from Names where vendor_name = '" + vendorName + "')"` and put a blank space next to every " character e.g. `" AND` instead of `"AND`

Answer (score 0):

According to me, this could be due to order of evaluation of user defined values embedded within the query. Could be the first dynamic value might be evaluated before the one in the inner query.

As I am not sure about the value to variable binding, however, I would recommend you to check following points;

a) externalise both your variable (vendor name and row id) outside and evaluate and ensure it has respective values

b) and then form your query statement with the evaluated values

May be you can debug and see the CommandText of command object just before call Execute.